# Fitnet function analogue in Octave

Tags: matlab, neural-network, octave

Octave is considered as open source implementation of MATLAB.

In MATLAB there is a function [**`fitnet`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/fitnet.html).

Does anybody know a corresponding function in Octave?

P.S.: I have also installed in my octave edition an [Octave´s neural network package](http://www.plexso.com/61_octave/index.html).

Or, maybe, does somebody know about some other package, which has this function?

Comment: Yura, what do you prefer to receive? Do you prefer a solution, that mimicks the MATLAB `fitnet()` behaviour as close as possible in your `octave`-code, or a solution, that enables your `octave`-code to work with a fully-fledged AI/ML neural-network based learner / predictor-engine?

Comment: I prefer solution that mimicks the MATLAB fitnet()

Comment: `fitnet` is an extension of the `feedforwardnet` so you will be able to mimic `fitnet`creating a new feed-fordward network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably want something like [NetLab](http://www.aston.ac.uk/eas/research/groups/ncrg/resources/netlab). The authors state that most of it works in Octave. There is a page with [examples](http://www.aston.ac.uk/eas/research/groups/ncrg/resources/netlab/book/worked-examples) that comes from a book about the software. From the [Intro](http://www.aston.ac.uk/eas/research/groups/ncrg/resources/netlab/how-to-use) on the site it looks like `netopt` is similar to `fitnet` in functionality, if not necessarily in syntax.